# Read Receipts of Emails in Flutter

Tags: flutter, email

I want to know that is there any way in Flutter for Read Receipts of E-mails that I sent to my users through in-app form?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking pixel is the solution.

Please refer to the following article for more information.

https://www.cookiepro.com/knowledge/tracking-pixel/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).